# iOS - APNS With InHouse Distribution

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, in-house-distribution

A common problem that is being faced by many developers, I'm posting it again as I couldn't get any right solution.
For distribution of apps using **InHouse** account (by OTA), how is it possible to send push notifications to the apps installed on devices. With development profile, everything works good during. The problem is when distribution only. 
How will Apple recognize that the bundle identifier is being used in house distributed application?

Comment: Did you create an separate certificate for the InHouse profile and send the push notification via the normal APNS server?

Comment: Yes, I'm having a InHouse distribution profile which is being used for distribution of apps. The main question is how will Apple know that its receiving payload for InHouse distribution application?

Comment: It does not, InHouse work in the same way an AdHoc build will work. Apple only uses different server for apps signed with a Development profile. All other (AdHoc, InHouse and AppStore) are going via de Live Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How will Apple recognize that the bundle identifier is being used in house distributed application?

Apple will recognize the app ID because you added (or should have) the app ID in the developer portal and created a provision profile that allows push notifications. If your problem is only with the distribution version, compare your development provision settings to the distribution provision settings in the portal.

APNS has nothing to do with the App Store or iTunesConnect; it works fine with enterprise distribution.