# Does APNs work with apps distributed inhouse using the Enterprise Distribution program?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, enterprise-distribution

Does  APNs work with apps distributed inhouse using the Enterprise Distribution program and distributed interanlly from a website?

I found this from [this link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ProvisioningDevelopment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH104-SW1) saying no, but I see vague comments in forums that it is possible:

Apple Push Notification service (APNs) is available only to apps distributed through the iOS App Store or Mac App Store. Your app must be provisioned and code signed to use app services. If you are a company, most of these configuration steps can be performed only by a team agent or admin.

This link has a comment indicating that it can be done.
[iOS - APNS With InHouse Distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18334057/ios-apns-with-inhouse-distribution)

Comment: Of course this can be done. Just create a provisioning profile which enable APNs and configure your server with the corresponding certificate. I don't see any problem

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply... So is the Apple documentation incorrect or am I missing something in the context of their statement?

Comment: I think the real APNs is for production only. For any other, this is another APNs instance, kind of sandboxed.

Comment: I have built an enterprise app that gets push notifications. Yes, it is doable. The configuration wasn't any different than configuring for App Store app.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can absolutely send Push Notifications to an Enterprise-signed application.  The AppID setup, device provisioning, server-side setup, push token registrations, etc. are exactly identical to the tools, process, servers, and APIs used when enabling Push Notifications for apps on the App Store or the Mac App Store.

The process starts by enabling the Push Notifications Entitlement on the AppID registered in your Enterprise Developer Account on the [Certificates, Identifiers, and Profiles](https://developer.apple.com/account) tool.  Apple's Push Notification documentation, has long standing issues with misstating that Push is only available to App Store / Mac App Store apps; it has always been a configurable service for Enterprise accounts despite what documentation leads you to believe.